# InfluxDB 2 storage retention/max. size

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I am using InfluxDB 2.2 to store & aggregate data on a gateway device. The environment is pretty limited regarding space. I do not know in which interval and how large the data is that get's ingested. Retention is not that much of a requirement. All I want is to make sure that the influx db does not grow larger than let's say 5GB.

I know that I could just set restrictive bounds to the retention but this does not feel like an ideal solution. Do you see any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are more concerned about the disk space. If so, there are several workaround you could try:

- **Retention policy**: this is similar to TTL in other NoSQL and it could help you to delete the obsolete data automatically. How long you should set the retention policy really depends on the business you are running. You could run the instance for a few days and see how the disk space is growing and then change your retention policy.
- **Downsampling**: "Downsampling is the process of aggregating high-resolution time series within windows of time and then storing the lower resolution aggregation to a new bucket ". not all data need to retrieved at all times. Most of the time, the fresher the data (i.e. hot data), the more frequent it will be fetched. What's more,  you might just need to see the big picture of historical data, i.e. less granular. For example, if you are collecting the data in second-level granularity, you could perform a downsampling task to only retain the mean of the indicator values at an minute or even hour precision instead. That will save you a lot of space while not affecting your trending view that much.

See more details [here](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/downsampling-influxdb-v2-0/).